# how to create event columnwidthchanging in usercontrol winform C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

- I create Form1 contain 1 usercontrol with name MyUserControl

  - and MyUserControl contains 1 listview have 4 columns with name column(Default,ID,Name,Position)

I want fire event ColumWidthChanging of ListView to no allow change width column listview

- so how do I do ?

please, somebody help me!!!

my code in MyUserControl:

```
public event EventHandler columnWidthChangingListViewCategoryClick;
    private void listView_Category_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (columnWidthChangingListViewCategoryClick != null)
        {
            columnWidthChangingListViewCategoryClick(sender, e);
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            e.NewWidth = 0;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

my code in Form1:

```
    My_UC.columnWidthChangingListViewCategoryClick += new EventHandler(columnWidthChangingListViewCategoryClick_MyUC);
private void columnWidthChangingListViewCategoryClick_MyUC(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

my code is not fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) which allows setting minimum, maximum width for each column and various styles (non-resizable, nonclickable, sortable etc.).